# Aplicar un WHERE a mi sentencia SQL en un SUM selectivo y total

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

chicos tengo el siguiente conflicto:

Poseo la siguiente sentencia SQL

```
SELECT SUM(monto) AS 'total',
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_pago = 'PENDIENTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'pendiente',
      SUM(CASE WHEN status_pago = 'APROBADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'aprobado'
    FROM pagos
```

Me da como resultado lo siguiente:

1. El total de la sumatoria de todos los montos de la columna monto
2. La cantidad de filas con estatus pendiente
3. y la cantidad de filas con estatus aprobado

y me gustaria tener adicionalmente un valor de la sumatoria de los montos donde el status sea igual a aprobado y lógicamente en la sentencia que tengo no puedo colocar esa condición con un WHERE ya que me alteraría el resultado de cantidad de filas con estatus pendiente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo tenes que hacer un pequeño cambio en tu query.

Ya lo tenes resuelto, pero en lugar de sumar 1 o 0, suma el monto o cero...

algo asi:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN status_pago = 'APROBADO' THEN monto ELSE 0 END) AS 'monto_aprobado'
```

Comment: Gracias..! En efecto es lo que requiero.. ya acepto tu gentil respuesta..!